# Aws lambda async and sync issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, lambda, synchronization, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where i need to query on a table then loop through the result and query another table inside a loop .. But i tried using **synchronize**  node js module . But sometime api ends with timeout error with this method. Now i am trying my code in below way but no luck.

```
    var notification = {
TableName: "Tablename", 
KeyConditionExpression:"#userId =:userid and #datetime <=:datetime", 
ScanIndexForward: false,
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#userId": "userId",
    "#datetime":"datetime"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":userid"    :userId,
    ":datetime"  :datetime
}
}; 

docClient.query(notification, function(err, result) {

if (err) {
    context.succeed({success: false, message : JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),method:"notification",type:type});
}else{

    result = result.Items;

    if (result.length>0) { 
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            result[k]['CafeDetail']=getDetail(result[k].CafeID,function (data) { 

            });

            if (k ==(result.length -1)) { 
                context.succeed({success: true,data:result, message : "Notification list",method:"notification",type:type}); 
            }

        }
    }

}

});

function getDetail(CafeID,callback) {
    var param = {
        TableName: "Tablename",
        ProjectionExpression:"CafeName,Cafe_MainImage",
        KeyConditionExpression:"CafeID =:cafeID", 
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":cafeID"    :CafeID
        }
    };

    docClient.query(param, function(err, CafeDetail) {
        if (err) {
            console.log (err)
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(CafeDetail.Items);
            console.log(CafeDetail.Items);
        }
    });
}
```

On output this variable (result[k]['CafeDetail']) is always coming as undefined . However console.log inside getDetail function print the result.

I am newbie to aws lambda with node js .. Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I just got solution to my question . So i am posting it,may be it will help someone else facing same issue

```
var notification = {
                    TableName: "Tablename", 
                    KeyConditionExpression:"#userId =:userid",
                    Limit: 12,
                    ScanIndexForward: false,
                    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                        "#userId": "userId",
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":userid"    :userId
                    }
                }; 

                docClient.query(notification, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        context.succeed({success: false, message : JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),method:"notification",type:type});
                    }else{
                        var ret =[];
                        var results =result.Items;
                        if (results.length>0) {
                            results.forEach(function(result, i) {
                                console.log(i);
                                var param = {
                                    TableName: "Tablename",
                                    ProjectionExpression:"CafeName,Cafe_MainImage",
                                    KeyConditionExpression:"CafeID =:cafeID", 
                                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                                        ":cafeID"    :result.CafeID
                                    }
                                };

                                docClient.query(param, function(err, CafeDetail) {
                                    if (err) { 
                                        context.succeed({success: false, message : JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),method:"notification",type:type});
                                    } else { 
                                        console.log(CafeDetail.Items);
                                        CafeDetail =CafeDetail.Items; 
                                        result['CafeDetail']=CafeDetail
                                        console.log(result);
                                        if (i === results.length -1) {  // last iteration
                                            context.succeed({success: true,data:results, message : "Notification list",method:"notification",type:type}); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }); 
                            }); 
                        }else{
                            context.succeed({success: true,data:result, message : "Notification list",method:"notification",type:type}); 
                        } 
                    }
                });
```